# I am getting an error with Epic Games saying 'Unsupported Graphics Card'

Tags: graphics-card, epic-games-launcher

I am a Windows 7 Home Premium user and I tried to boot up Rocket League when I got an error saying the following: 'There is a problem with your graphics card. Please ensure your card meets the minimum system requirements and that you have the latest drivers installed.' However, my graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti) does meet system requirements and has the latest drivers. I am unsure what the problem is.

Comment: Does you CPU have integrated graphics, and is that what you are using by accident perhaps?

Comment: Im not entirely sure, how do you check, may I ask.

Comment: You can find out what CPU your computer has, and then research if it has an integrated GPU - if it doesn't then the game has no choice but to use your GTX 1050 Ti.  If your CPU does have an integrated GPU, you can also try following [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/72576/163757).  Though the question I linked is for a Steam game, it should be the same process, you'll just need to know where the Rocket League executable is at on your computer.  Once you set this, see if the error is resolved.

Comment: I researched it and I discovered that my GPU is not integrated. So now do I have to check the GTX 1050 Ti or check Epic Games itself?

Comment: I *think* you misunderstand what I mean.  You need to check if your **CPU** has integrated graphics (probably something like Intel HD Graphics if it does).  To do this, find out what your **CPU** is, and look it up (Intel has documented on [their site](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html) all of their CPUs and if they have integrated graphics).  If you can determine that your CPU has integrated graphics, then you need to determine if the game is trying use your integrated graphics, rather than your dedicated GPU (which is the GTX 1050 Ti).

Comment: Okay, that answered my question. the GPU thing was a misclick rofl. Thanks, I will get back to you to see if I got it and to see if i need help etc.